# Generating small text with Imagemagick is blurry

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to generate an image using Imagemagick to match a preview in the browser, but the text comes out blurry.  Does anybody have any suggestions?  Attached is an image with the Imagemagick one on top, and browser one on bottom, along with the IM code.

```
convert -density 288 -resize 25% -background white -fill black -strokewidth 0 -stroke white -font Rubik-Regular.ttf -pointsize 10 -gravity center label:'This is a TEST!' label_arial.gif
```

[image]

Comment: Try putting the -resize 25% at the end (just before the output file name)

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to start with `caption` which automatically sizes the text the best way to fill a given area. So, as your lettering is around 140x36 pixels, you would do:

```
convert -size 140x36 -gravity center caption:'This is a TEST!' label.gif
```

[image]

Comment: My issue is I need the text to be font-size 10, and it looks terrible with both label and caption.  I'm beginning to think ImageMagick is the wrong tool for the job.